# Better visualization of jenkins multi configuration jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have a plain jenkins maven job that triggers a multi configuration job if it succeeds. The multi configuration job executes a simple build step on 3 slaves.

I am not quite satisfied with how I get to the log of the build step being run on a specific slave and how I can see the status of the build step on the slave.

I have looked at:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin

And tried to add my build flow. But the build pipeline plugin does not really have any support for showing each slave as a job in a multi configuration job.

Anyone facing the same challenge and found some good plugins?

Comment: what did you use in the end?

Answer (score 3):

Try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin

It displays well a **Multi-configuration project**, and also works with **Dynamic Axis**, that creates dynamic name for the Multi-configuration sub-project.

Once you create a new *Delivery Pipeline View*, add each instance of the Multi-configuration sub-project (into the *Initial Job*).

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Multi Job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

It looks like this works with multi config (matrix)

Where the first phase runs all the configurations in 'matrix-label and the second phase runs just when AXIS (which is my axis label) is 1 or 2

[image: Multi Job running Matrix Job]

Comment: So have you defined your axis using "Label Expression" to make the above work or is it the label that you have defined in the Node Management for each node?

Comment: Its a user defined label here, mainly as I don't have any nodes defined on this configuration